# Is there a way to get datatype long php?

Tags: php, xml, soap, types, custom-data-type

Can I convert my int datatype variable to longint datatype because I need the object type to be long for soap API (XML)?

Comment: PHP has only one type of integer, which is 64 bits signed on a 64-bit system, so at least as wide if not "longer" than most definitions of "longint". Can you explain the actual problem you're having?

Comment: [XSD has a type called "long" (not "longint")](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/#long) which does correspond to the range of a signed 64-bit integer. Is this the type you need? If so then, then there should be no problem having a regular PHP integer to populate it. There is also an ["unsignedLong"](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/#unsignedLong), which has a wider range than PHP's integers, but that's only a problem if you need a number larger than 2**63.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert PHP variables/arrays and object you can use SoapVar
to know further about [SoapVar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php)

for your task you need something like
$workOrder['ID'] = new SoapVar($data['ID'],XSD_LONG);

to convert PHP object into Soap Object follow the below code, hopefully it will help you in solving your problem

```
    $workOrder  = [];
    $workOrder['ID'] = new SoapVar($data['ID'],XSD_LONG);
    $note = [];
    $note['body'] = "valid note body";
    $note['date'] = new SoapVar("2022-07-18",XSD_DATETIME);
    $note['private'] = true;
    $note['subject'] = "valid note subject";

    $varNote = new SoapVar($note, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'ns3:Note', null);
    $varWorkOrder = new SoapVar($workOrder, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'ns3:WorkOrder', null);
    try{
       $response2 = $client->attachNoteToWorkOrder($varNote,$varWorkOrder);
    }catch (\SoapFault $exception){
        // dd($exception);
        dd($client->__getLastRequest());
    }

    dd($response2);
```